# how to remove specific cookie value?

Tags: android, cookies, cookiemanager

In my app there are facebook and twitter login using browser and after login it stores cookies automatically. 
i have to logout facebook that will be happen to remove facebook cookies value but i don't know how to remove particular cookies.

if i remove all cookies using:

```
CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance(this);
cm.removeAllCookies();
```

but it removes all cookies value means it will logout both facebook and twitter both.

my question is -- how to remove particular cookie value.

thanks..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940012/android-cookiemanager-setcookie-creates-multiple-cookies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `CookieManager.setCookie()` and set the cookie to the empty string.  Something like this should work:

```
String cookieString = "cookieName=''";
cookieManager.setCookie(cookieDomain, cookieString);
```

In addition to setting the cookie value to empty, you can also expire the cookie by setting the 'expire' value in the cookie string to a time in the past. For example:

```
String cookieString = "cookieName=;expires=Mon, 17 Oct 2011 10:47:11 UTC;";
```

Comment: The part of the answer which states that setting expiry value to a time in the past does not work. This is clearly mentioned in the javadoc [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)))

"The cookie being set will be ignored if it is expired."

I also verified the same in Android 4.2.1 device.

Comment: tried this and seems to be not working. Also digged the code and there seems to be no removal when we enter empty value