# How to remove cookie for facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, cookies

Has anyone here knows about how to remove facebook cookies?
Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802364/how-to-remove-specific-cookie-value)!

I've tried to use facebook SDK for android, I found some cookies and try to remove them. But they seem cannot be removed.

Let's say there was a cookie named "c_user".

```
myCookieManager.setCookie("m.facebook.com","c_user=;expires=Mon, 17 Oct 2011 10:47:11 UTC;");
```

I thought the cookies should had been removed. But it didn't! Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this facebook API method:

```
com.facebook.android.Util.clearCookies()
```