# Android CookieManager setCookie creates multiple cookies

Tags: android, mobile, cookies

In my android application I have a webview. It loads URLs from multiple domains. I need to delete all cookies from a specific domain. I want to keep cookies from other domains. But I need to delete all cookies from one domain.  I'm open to all other solutions that handles my request. (note that domain uses both http and https)

But when I try to use CookieManager.setCookie, all available cookies for that domain didn't deleted. Multiple cookie keys appeear when I try to write to that keys.

I attach my code below. You can find results in comment lines. At the end of story I get this cookie. Note for multiple values:

```
"userid=12%34; token=12ased; remember_check=0; userid='-1'; token='-1'; remember_check='-1';"
```

My helper function that splits cookie string to get cookie keys:

```
public static Vector<String> getCookieAllKeysByCookieString(String pCookies) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pCookies)) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] cookieField = pCookies.split(";");
    int len = cookieField.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cookieField[i] = cookieField[i].trim();
    }
    Vector<String> allCookieField = new Vector<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cookieField[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!cookieField[i].contains("=")) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] singleCookieField = cookieField[i].split("=");
        allCookieField.add(singleCookieField[0]);
    }
    if (allCookieField.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return allCookieField;
}
```

I get present cookies:

```
// I take cookie string for specific URL
mCookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
String url2="https://mysite.com";
String cookieString = mCookieManager.getCookie(url2);
Toast.makeText(mContext, "cookie string:\n"+cookieString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// result is: userid=12%34; token=12ased; remember_check=0;
```

Then I call to replace old cookies.

```
Vector<String> cookie = CookieUtil.getCookieAllKeysByCookieString(cookieString);
if (cookie == null || cookie.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "cookie null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
if (cookie != null) {
    int len = cookie.size();
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "cookie number: "+len, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // result is, cookie number: 3
    String cookieNames="";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cookieNames += "\n"+cookie.get(i) ;
        mCookieManager.setCookie(url2, cookie.get(i) + "='-1';");
    }
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "cookieNames:\n"+cookieNames, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // result is: "cookienames: userid token remember_check"

    mCookieSyncManager.sync();

    cookieString = mCookieManager.getCookie(url2);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "cookie string:\n"+cookieString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mCookieSyncManager.sync();
    // result is: "userid=12%34; token=12ased; remember_check=0; userid='-1'; token='-1'; remember_check='-1';"
}
```

Edit:
I also tried setCookie like this:

```
mCookieManager.setCookie(url2, cookie.get(i) + "=-1;");
mCookieManager.setCookie(url2, cookie.get(i) + "=-1");
```

Edit2: setCookie's signature is like this:

```
 /**
 * Sets a cookie for the given URL. Any existing cookie with the same host,
 * path and name will be replaced with the new cookie. The cookie being set
 * must not have expired and must not be a session cookie, otherwise it
 * will be ignored.
 *
 * @param url the URL for which the cookie is set
 * @param value the cookie as a string, using the format of the 'Set-Cookie'
 *              HTTP response header
 */
public void setCookie(String url, String value) {
    throw new MustOverrideException();
}
```

Although I get same keys inside cookie string (`"userid=12%34; token=12ased; remember_check=0; userid='-1'; token='-1'; remember_check='-1';"`) will they have different host or path ?

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar experience with the [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) in Android. Setting the same cookie will indeed add it as a new cookie.

Please try to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621738/1557187). It will enable you to `flush` the cookies you want to `remove` and then you'll be able to set the again as you desire.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried the expire methods and still no go.  I call removeExpiredCookie afterwards, and the cookies still remain the same.  Also when you add the expire to the cookie value, I think setCookie ignores it.

Answer (score 2):

1. **First**, we can delete the cookie via CookieManager's interfaces:

   ```
    setCookie(URL, 'COOKIE_KEY=;');
   ```
2. **Then**, we need to find out the correct URL, considering both **Domain** and **Path** attributes of the cookie.

   For example, the following cookie

   ```
    document.cookie = 'COOKIE_NAME=COOKIE_VAL; path=/; domain=.example.com;'
   ```

   **can** be deleted by

   ```
    setCookie('.example.com', 'COOKIE_NAME=;')
   ```

   and **cannot** be deleted by

   ```
    setCookie('www.example.com/info.html', 'COOKIE_NAME=;')
   ```
3. **Finally**, here is an example to remove a cookie.

   ```
    String[] kvPairs = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url).split(" ");           
    for (String kvPair : kvPairs) {
        String newPair = kvPair.replaceAll("=.*", "=;");
        // Delete the cookie asynchronously.
        CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, newPair);
    }
   ```